# How to process JavaScript blob in python?

Tags: javascript, python, audio, blob

I want to process an audio blob in python that is received via socketio from a javascript client.

I want the audio data as numpy array to process it, but I don't seem to be able to convert the blob properly.

The audio blob contains:

```
[Float32Array[32768], Float32Array[32768]]
```

In python, I tried:

```
@socketio.on('gotaudio')
def get_audio(blob):  
    //CONVERT THE BLOB
    data = blob[0]
    dat = np.array(json.loads(data));
    //DO SOME SIGNAL PROCESSING
    fftData=abs(np.fft.rfft(dat))**2;
    ....
```

But this throws the error:

> TypeError: expected string or buffer

How can I transform the audio blob correctly so that it can be processed with np.fft?

Comment: For the love of $DEITY, please tell me that you are not actually transmitting audiodata encapsulated in a JSON string.

Comment: Quite. :-) I don't know socket.io specifically, but I can tell that generic WebSockets can transmit binary data (Uint8Arrays [JS] / bytes [Python]).

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using `base64.b64decode()` on it first? (base64 is in the standard lib)

It would help to get an example blob.